# display limited item in template-Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I queried the date from table using

```
  author=Author.objects.all()
```

and in template just displayed the variable `{{ author }}`.So if 10 items are in table,i don't want to show all 10items,instead i need to show `1st 3 items` and for indicating more data available with 3dots(...)

Required is like this `Python,Django,Pycharm...`

How to do this.

Comment: Both answers are worked for me,Now the items are displaying without separation like comma(,)how to separate the each item with comma

Comment: `{% if not forloop.last %},{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
authors = Author.objects.all()

{% for author in authors|slice:":3" %}
    {{ author }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% if authors|length > 3 %}...{% else %}.{% endif %}
```

or simply just [slice](http://www.diveintopython3.net/native-datatypes.html#slicinglists) the queryset in the first place:

```
authors = Author.objects.all()[:3]

{% for author in authors %}{{ author }}{% endfor %}...
```

Comment: I've always thought than should exists a shortcut for this scenario.

Comment: Yea, a `truncateiterable` filter would be nice